# I am using ng-options to show data in select box but in option i have one hard-coded value is No-search how to show that value select at first

Tags: angularjs

```
<div class="filter-box">
    <select ng-model="$ctrl.customModel" 
            ng-options= 'option.id as option.name for option in transactionstatusList'
            ng-change="transactionStatusChange()"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected">No Search</option>
    </select> 
</div>
```

I am using angularjs ng-options to show data in select box but in option i have one hard-coded value is No-search how to show that value select at first because when data comes dynamically it shows first value from the data

Comment: where do you use `ng-show`? I dont see it in code

Comment: sorry my mistake , m using ng-options to show the data

Comment: what angularjs version do you use?

Comment: 1.5.9 this version m using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work well if you have undefined `customModel`.

```
$scope.customModel;
```

<kbd>[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/61dn130u/)</kbd>

However, if `$scope.customModel` is predefined, after async call, selected option jumps regards to `ng-model`

<kbd>[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/wdLgx0g5/)</kbd>